# Customize IOS Background Audio Play Controls with Flutter just_audio_background Package

Tags: ios, flutter, just-audio

I am making an Flutter IOS app that depends on just_audio and just_audio_background. Implementing all the main functions was very straightforward with the help of documentation. However, I got stuck when I wanted to change the (next audio/previous audio) control buttons to (fast forward/rewind) buttons on the lock screen ([shown by the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylBXo.png)).

I saw there are **fastForwardInterval** and **rewindInterval** params for the JustAudioBackground.init() function, but changing them does not seem to have any effect on the button configuration.

Does anyone have any experience with solving this issue? Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use audio_service (https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) that is just_audio_background also based on.

Answer (score 0):

Issues should be reported via GitHub, this includes feature requests. Note that the most similar existing feature request is here:

https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/912